# how to find a character in string in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, union

i am working with sql and got stuck in issue,

i am using `sql server 2012 r2.`

i have a `table (info)` with 2 `columns id (int) and names varchar(max).`

in the names column i have stored coma(,) separated list of `names, like marry,rita,johan,david,.`

now i want to get the id where names is david.

```
select id from info where names='david'
```

how it is possible in sql, i know we can do it in c# by using string.substing but is it possible in sql?

Comment: If my answer get you what you are looking for, feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others in future to find the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM info
WHERE names LIKE '%david%'
```

It will return the `id` of the record if the column `names` contains 'david'.

Read more about `LIKE` operator [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Comment: That will also return records where the list contains davidson.